# Open URL automatically without any click in PHP script

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have written a php script that is used to download any youtube video, it works on 2 buttons, first button is used to create the formats and second button starts downloading, 
I want that if i press, first button, 2nd button, automatically did its work, and start download on single click,

Here is the code for first button,

```
<button id="videoDownloadButton" type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg"          data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" onClick="downloadVideo();">MP4 Quality</button>
```

Javssript on that button is....

```
function downloadVideo() {
var videoID = player.getVideoData()['video_id']
document.getElementById("downloadFormatList").innerHTML="Please wait. Processing...";
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp3 = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else { // code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp3 = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
 }
xmlhttp3.onreadystatechange=function() {
if (xmlhttp3.readyState==4 && xmlhttp3.status==200) {
        document.getElementById("downloadFormatList").innerHTML=xmlhttp3.responseText;
}
}

 //keyword = keyword.replace(/ /g, '%2B');
  xmlhttp3.open("GET","TMB/download.php?videoid="+videoID,true);
xmlhttp3.send();

}
```

and after that PHP script will work and produce that second button, Which is a HTML tag,

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['videoid'])) {
$my_id = $_REQUEST['videoid'];

if(strpos($my_id,"https://youtu.be/") !== false)
{
$my_id = str_replace("https://youtu.be/","",$my_id);
}
}


<?php

//$my_video_info = 'http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?&video_id='.            $my_id;
 $my_video_info = 'http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?&video_id=' .       $my_id . '&asv=3&el=detailpage&hl=en_US'; //video details fix *1
 $my_video_info = curlGet($my_video_info);
 /* TODO: Check return from curl for status code */
 $thumbnail_url = $title = $url_encoded_fmt_stream_map = $type = $url = '';
 parse_str($my_video_info);
 ?>



<?php
 $my_title     = $title;
 $cleanedtitle = clean($title);
 if (isset($url_encoded_fmt_stream_map)) {
  /* Now get the url_encoded_fmt_stream_map, and explode on comma */
  $my_formats_array = explode(',', $url_encoded_fmt_stream_map);
 if ($debug) {
echo '<pre>';
print_r($my_formats_array);
echo '</pre>';
}
} else {
 echo '<p>No encoded format stream found.</p>';
 echo '<p>Here is what we got from YouTube:</p>';
 echo $my_video_info;
 }
 if (count($my_formats_array) == 0) {
echo '<p>No format stream map found - was the video id correct?</p>';
exit;
  }
   /* create an array of available download formats */
   $avail_formats[] = '';
   $i               = 0;
    $ipbits          = $ip = $itag = $sig = $quality = '';
    $expire          = time();
  foreach ($my_formats_array as $format) {
 parse_str($format);
$avail_formats[$i]['itag']    = $itag;
$avail_formats[$i]['quality'] = $quality;
$type                         = explode(';', $type);
$avail_formats[$i]['type']    = $type[0];
$avail_formats[$i]['url']     = urldecode($url) . '&signature=' . $sig;
parse_str(urldecode($url));
$avail_formats[$i]['expires'] = date("G:i:s T", $expire);
$avail_formats[$i]['ipbits']  = $ipbits;
$avail_formats[$i]['ip']      = $ip;
$i++;
}


echo '<div class="format_list">';
echo '<br>';
echo '<table>';

 /* now that we have the array, print the options */
 for ($i = 0; $i < 1; $i++) {
  if ($config['VideoLinkMode'] == 'direct' || $config['VideoLinkMode'] ==       'both')
 ?> <tr><td><?php
 echo $avail_formats[$i]['type'];
 ?></td>

<td><small>(<?php
  echo $avail_formats[$i]['quality'];
 ?>)</small> </td>
<td><small><span class="size"><?php
  echo formatBytes(get_size($avail_formats[$i]['url']));
?></span></small>
</td>

<td><a href="<?php
  echo $avail_formats[$i]['url'];
?> '&title='<?php
 echo $cleanedtitle;
?>'" class="downloadButton">Record Video</a></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
 ?>
```

This is the button, that i want to did its work automatically

```
<a href="<?php
  echo $avail_formats[$i]['url'];
?> '&title='<?php
 echo $cleanedtitle;
?>'" class="downloadButton">Record Video</a>
```

Comment: Using JavaScript check if this DOM element mean this button exist then fire a click event against it. If you have any confusion i can write code for it.

Comment: oh please, i am thankful for you, write it

Answer (score 0):

try this instead of your second button code.

```
header('Location:' .$avail_formats[$i][url]. '&title=' .$cleanedtitle);
```

Answer (score 0):

Any event handlers attached with .on() or one of its shortcut methods are triggered when the corresponding event occurs. They can be fired manually, however, with the .trigger() method. A call to .trigger() executes the handlers in the same order they would be if the event were triggered naturally by the user:

```
$( "#foo" ).on( "click", function() {
  alert( $( this ).text() );
});
if($("required-button").length>0){
$( "#foo" ).trigger( "click" );
}
```

here is the reference to reference of my [example](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

Comment: Let me check this, and then i'll talk to you

Comment: how, i attach it, with that button.?

Comment: give some id to button then you will able to get it .

Comment: <a  href="<?php echo $avail_formats[$i]['url']; ?> '&title='<?php echo      $config['VideoLinkMode'] ?>'" id="foo" >Record Video</a></td>
  '
    <script>
     $( "#foo" ).on( "click", function() {
   alert( $( this ).text() );
   });
   if($("required-button").length>0){
   $( "#foo" ).trigger( "click" );
   }

              </script>'

Comment: just did this, but it still require the button

Comment: do you have any error in console. I had simply check that if this button exist then fired a click event against this button .